# show button instead of menu bar when browser resize in css/html

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu in my web page, and i want to show a button instead of these menu-bar when browser size below certain level (below some size) And vice verse . I need the code.
how it works ? Is it pure CSS or i need to apply any java script/ code

here is the example web page [Sample site](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/)

above is the sample page . if u change the size of the browser (about half ) u will see a menu button on top-right corner. and if u maximize it will disappears and shows the menu-bar instead of that(menu button)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Aside from that, post some relevant HTML/CSS/JS here demonstrating a specific problem.

Comment: Are you asking about responsive?

Comment: Use  @media (max-width: 600px) {...} and jquery is needed to replace the menu/list items to buttons.

Comment: @JoshC  when browser width reaches 400px (for example) i need to show a button menu instead of those lengthy menu-bar , and the browser size is larger than 400px i want to show the menu-bar. button means a menu button ( with all the menu-bar optins)

Comment: @TamilSelvan sir i dont know that is responsive ? or not i am very new to html and css . what is responsive ?

Comment: @SagarGuhe Can u give me the code ? and is it possible to make it out without Jquery or Javascript

Comment: @WeAreCop11 Google for [Responsive web design](https://www.google.co.in/#q=responsive+web+design)

Comment: Responsive is a web design which adapt according to the browser size. you are talking about responsive only.

Comment: hardly possible without jquery i think let me give time while i try to create the code snippet.

Comment: @SagarGuhe this is the sample page http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/  if u change the size of the browser u will see a menu button on top-right corner. and if u maximize it will disappears and shows the munu-bar instead of that

Comment: I got the answer : just use @media

Comment: <style type="text/css">
   li
   {
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
   }
   @media ( min-width:768px )
   {
    #btn
    {
     display:none;
    }
    
   }
   (at)media ( max-width: 766px )
   {
    #menu
    {
     display:none;
    }
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem.

[Demo](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly) : courtesy Osvaldas dot info

Comment: thanx alot Sagar Guhe ,this is what i expect... thanks alot man

Answer (score 0):

This tutorials will help you to learn about responsive designing and also to get a menu the way you want.
[**Link**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXVoqJEwqoQ)
courtesy: Coder's Guide